# C++: Searching an array of strings that begin with a given prefix

Tags: c++, string, vector, substring, prefix

Suppose I am given an string vector `vector<string> names = {"ab","abs","act","add"}`.  I am also given a string prefix `string prefix ("ab")`.  My job is to populate another string vector (let's call it `vector<string> name_list`) with all the names that begin with the given prefix.  Currently I am doing this by simply using a string compare function like follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i)
{
    if (names[i].compare(0, prefix.size(), prefix) == 0) // If name begins with prefix
        (*name_list).push_back(names[i]);
}
```

This works well for small vectors. In the example above the output would be `["ab","abs"]` My question is if this is the most efficient algorithm when the `names` has let's say millions of strings in it.  If not, what other algorithms could be used?

Comment: To save some memory you could read the strings into a trie

Comment: I think using a suffix array can reduce the number of comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the iterator retrned by `std::set<std::string>::lower_bound(prefix)` and search linearly forward.

```
std::set<std::string> names {"ab","abs","act","add"};
std::string prefix = "ab";
auto itr = names.lower_bound(prefix);
while (itr != names.end() && !prefix.compare(*itr, 0, prefix.size())) {
     // matching string
     ++itr;
}
```